# Should the Unused Contact of a DPDT Relay be Connected in Parallel or Series?

Tags: switches, relay

I am designing a PCB which uses a [5-1462039-6](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-potter-brumfield-relays/5-1462039-6/PB2083TR-ND/4924668) DPDT relay. I actually only need one of the relay contacts, but this relay was cheaper than any equivalent SPST relay I could find. Is there any advantage to connecting the second relay contact either in parallel (as shown in the picture) or in series? Or would it be better to just use one contact and leave the second unconnected?

[image: DPDT Relay Schematic Drawing]

I already know that connecting in parallel will not allow me to double the amount of current the relay can handle, since the two contacts might not switch at the exact same moment. One advantage to connecting in parallel I could think of is that if one of the contacts eventually became stuck open, the circuit would still work as long as the other contact still worked. However, if the contacts were more likely to become stuck closed rather than open, it would actually be better to connect them in series instead. Is one of these modes of failure more common in this type of relay, or is there any other advantage to either connecting the second contact in parallel, series, or not at all?

**Edit:** This relay is used as an auxiliary dry contact output. The user can connect the relay contacts to another device in order to trigger it to do something. The relay will be triggered by some sort of event, turn on for a configurable amount of time (usually no more than a few seconds), then turn off again.

Comment: It depends on the safe failure state that your circuit being switched requires. Please can you add details of the job it's doing, editing the question rather than adding comments. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM I added some details to the post

Comment: Ryan it depends on the application. If the relay is powering say a heater that will, if left on, get so hot it will start a fire, you want a higher probability it will fail open. But that mode is also less efficient. See my answer in the possible duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious disadvantage of connecting in series would be that you are doubling the contact resistance of the current path, resulting in more wasted power.

As you mentioned, by paralleling them you provide some redundancy which is useful. Additionally, ignoring the transient switching, you are essentially halving the contact resistance which should run more efficiently.

As @TonyM mentioned in the comments, you need to assess from a safety perspective which failure mode is preferred (fail close, fail often) but from a power perspective running them in parallel is preferred.